# Getting the center point of an NSView

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview

I need to get the center point of a NSView in the form of a CGPoint, how can I achieve this?
I am basically looking for the equivalent of the UIKit, UIView.center

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code will get you that CGPoint:

```
CGPointMake((myView.frame.origin.x + (myView.frame.size.width / 2)),
            (myView.frame.origin.y + (myView.frame.size.height / 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish NSView had a center property like UIView.

Comment: @user668518: So make one. It'll be better anyway to use your property/method everywhere you need the center than to copy and paste the coordinate-math code.

Comment: But this is correct only when the nsview wasn't rotated. After rotation origin is moved and center point your above calculations are incorrect.

Comment: You can use a class extension to do so.

Comment: This does not take `CALayer#transform` into account, like `UIView#center` does.

Answer (score 19):

A simple and easy to read way is:

```
CGPointMake(NSMidX(myView.frame), NSMidY(myView.frame))
```

I would suggest making this code, a category on NSView with a read only property named `center`.

Comment: +1 for NSMidX, wouldn't recommend naming it 'center' though. There already is a -(void)center method on NSWindow so might resolve wrong, and it's a fairly obvious name so Apple might use it as well, but maybe implement it slightly differently and things will break.

Comment: @uliwitness NSWindow does not inherit from NSView, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: `NSWindow` doesn't inherit from `NSView`, but nobody's stopping Apple from adding a `-center` method to NSView in the future, and then you get *really* interesting behavior. So when adding categories to Apple classes, it's always a good idea to either use a prefix like `foo_center`, or to at least stay away from the obvious names.

Answer (score 1):

To get an NSPoint of the center, you can just get the x-coordinate of the origin and add (width/2), and get the y-coordinate of the origin and add (height/2). Then you can convert it into a CGPoint.