# Using an NSProgressIndicator in an NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsprogressindicator

I'm using this code (inspired by an other question on here) :

```
- (void)showProgressIndicator {

    if (statusItem) {

        NSLog(@"wassup");
        NSView *progressIndicatorHolder = [[NSView alloc] init];
        NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] init];
        [progressIndicator setBezeled: NO];
        [progressIndicator setStyle: NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];
        [progressIndicator setControlSize: NSSmallControlSize];
        [progressIndicator sizeToFit];
        [progressIndicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];
        [progressIndicatorHolder addSubview:progressIndicator];
        [progressIndicator startAnimation:self];
        [statusItem setView:progressIndicatorHolder];
        [progressIndicator setNextResponder:progressIndicatorHolder];
        [progressIndicatorHolder setNextResponder:statusItem];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as this code runs the status item (which is initially showing an image) disappears... Why doesn't my code work?

Comment: (1) You're using ARC, right?  (2) What size is the view `progressIndicatorHolder`?  If you explicitly set the `frame` of `progressIndicatorHolder` does this help?

Comment: (1) yes (2) I don't specify the size but apparently its width is 0. Gonna try a couple of things now...

Comment: So I explicitly set the `frame` of `progressIndicatorHolder` and it worked okay but for some reason the progress indicator isn't centered (it's too low). How would I go from here? And is it okay to explicitly assign a `frame` like that?

Comment: You may need to [manually center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560842/getting-the-center-point-of-an-nsview).  As an alternative, if you want to do more sophisticated layout, you could put the custom view in a nib and load it on demand when you create the view for `NSStatusItem`.

Comment: okay thanks Alan! if you want make your comments an answer and i'll pick it as best since it solved my issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly set the `frame` on `progressIndicatorHolder` then center `progressIndicator` within its superview, e.g.:

```
CGRect holderRect = progressIndicatorHolder.bounds;
CGRect indicatorRect = progressIndicatorHolder.frame;
indicatorRect.origin.x = (holderRect.size.width - indicatorRect.size.width)/2.0f;
indicatorRect.origin.y = (holderRect.size.height - indicatorRect.size.height)/2.0f;
progressIndicator.frame = indicatorRect;
```

As an alternative, if you find that you want to do more sophisticated layout, you could load the `NSStatusItem`'s view from a nib.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me.

```
progressIndicator = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] init];

[progressIndicator setBezeled: YES];
[progressIndicator setStyle: NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];
[progressIndicator setControlSize: NSSmallControlSize];
[progressIndicator sizeToFit];
[progressIndicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];

oldView = [statusItem view];
[statusItem setView:progressIndicator];

[progressIndicator sizeToFit];
[statusItem setView:progressIndicator];
[progressIndicator startAnimation:self];
```

Please note progressIndicatorHolder is not being set anywhere.