# How can I CGWarpMouseCursorPosition() to the center of an NSView?

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nswindow, cgrect

I am trying to create a game where the mouse is locked at the center of the screen. To complete this task, I found the appropriate method: [`CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456387-cgwarpmousecursorposition)

Then I searched for how to get the center of an `NSView` and found this: [Getting the center point of an NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6560842/16217248)

I used the provided answers but get incorrect results. No matter where window is is, the point the mouse is moved to is always half of the frame width and height away from the top left corner of the screen. It is as if the `frame.origin` of the view is always `{0, 0}` even when the window is somewhere else.

In my code, `window` is a member inherited from implementing `NSWindowController` and `NSWindowDelegate`:

```
override func mouseMoved(with Event: NSEvent) {
    if let window = window, let view = window.contentView {
        let frame = view.frame
        CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY))
        // ...
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to get the center point of an `NSView` for use with the `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()` function?

Comment: See [Coordinate Systems Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIFCIHJ). The documentation of methods that return or use coordinates mentions the coordinate space. `NSView` can convert coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the existing implementation. The reason why `view.frame.origin` is always `{0, 0}` is because the `view.frame` is **relative to the window** and not **absolute**. As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69456699/16217248) states the frame origin is always at `{0, 0}` *'inside'* the window. I was expecting the `frame` to be absolute.

This can be solved by using `window.frame` directly instead of `view.frame`.

A second problem is that even if the `frame` is *'absolute'* the coordinate system used by `NSView` is different from the coordinate system used by `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()`. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19887161/16217248) explains how to convert between them.

**Corrected code:**

```
if let window = window, let view = window.contentView {
    let frame = window.frame
    let originY = NSScreen.main.frame.maxY-frame.maxY;
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: originY+frame.height*0.5))
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is as if window.contentView.frame.origin is always {0, 0} even though it is not

Yes it is. The content view is "inside" the window, with its origin located at the window's corner, as it were. That is why you cannot set the content view's frame: it has nowhere that it can go.

Perhaps what you wanted to know was where the window's own `frame` is?

Comment: Oh. But when I use `Window.frame`, its as though the `origin.y` is flipped, so I also get the wrong point

Comment: What do you mean by "flipped"? With respect to what? I mean, this is a Mac, the coordinate system origin is at the bottom left. That's not what you're seeing?

Comment: But when I use `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`, it is as if the origin is at the top left

Comment: I believe the question you actually asked is answered. Your new question is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884363/in-objective-c-os-x-is-the-global-display-coordinate-space-used-by-quartz-d